# Mass Storage Memory Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, usb-mass-storage

I need to open in device's Mass Storage Memory (`internal`, `external` and `usb Mass Storage`) through programmatically using `Intent`.

How to open Mass Storage Memory?

Comment: am also eager to know anser if this is possible

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible using stock Android without having 3 party applications installed.